# How can I provide paths to resource files in a binary release?

Tags: c++, cmake, resources, installation

I'm the maintainer of a library that comes bundled with `.xsd` files for XML validation. Currently, users need to tell the library where these files live by setting an environment variable. I would like to be able to compile in the location, as forgetting to set the environment variable is a common issue.

I can do this if you're building the library from source. Since the build system (CMake) knows the install path, it can just set a preprocessor definition pointing to the directory where the XSD files go.

When it comes to distributing a pre-compiled release, this doesn't work, since the paths on the build server aren't going to align with the users'.

The installation directory structure looks like this:

```
<install_dir>
    - conf/
      - foo.xsd
      - bar.xsd
    - lib/
      - mylib.a
```

How can I tell `mylib.a` where `foo.xsd` lives, without using absolute paths that will be specific to the build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know the relative layout of your files after installing (you *should*).

Obtain the absolute path of your executable at runtime (all operating systems have ways of doing that).

Then construct a path to your resource file relative to your executable, using your knowledge of your files relative install location.

Now load the resource using the path you constructed.

Comment: The issue is that there is no executable (aside from a couple toy programs to demonstrate usage of the library). Is there a way to make it work with just the static library?

Comment: @jon at runtime, there *will* be an executable (that your lib is linked with). That executable has a path. As long as your resource file is always installed in a specific location relative to where that executable is installed, you're golden - and ensuring shouldn't be too hard when you build the installer/package for the program.

Comment: @jon an alternative is to simply embed the resource file *in* the library and then read it from memory after the library is loaded.